# Any problem in drawing with Canvas outside UIthread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, bitmap, draw

I have a somewhat intensive drawing task that I want to move to a separate worker thread outside of UI thread. I would not update UI in this thread, only draw bitmaps and text in my own Canvas object and then post that object afterwards to an ImageView, using runOnUiThread.

Is there any drawback or side effect on doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Well I would consider this akin to having to load images from files for situations such as twitter and contact lists. Post a stand in to the UI, process the images asynchronously, then refresh the view with the new image.

The Twitter app should be able to be used for inspiration.